# Spark Job Hangs Indefinitely with no Task executed and no error [K8S]

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I have a spark application that was successfuly running on K8S in Airflow for quite some time. After deploying a new image, each of my three pipelines get stuck at some stage (toPandas() and count() operations) and waits there until my run in Airflow times out. Aside from internal company packages, I have also update Spark 3.2.0 to 3.3.0.

What bothers me however is how unusual the error seem to be - there is no explicit issue, in Spark History Server the stage is just never deserialised and send over network to executors, hence they keep on running idle (long, green, constant bars for each executor in Spark UI). I did not make any changes to the pipelines and code logic, so it has to do with some dependency issues. There is no OOM error, drivers and executors sizes are well within limits (those are also not huge datasets). The integration tests running the pipeline locally on small sample data also succeed. I feel really out of my depth on this one, so would be thankful for any suggestions!